# Communication complexity of median of two sets

Tags: discussion

I am working on exercise 1.6 of the textbook Communication Complexity and Applications by Anup Rao and Amir Yehudayoff.

Alice and Bob get **sets** X and Y in {1,2,...,n} respectively and they want to compute median of X union Y. The exercise asks to show a lower bound of Omega( n / log n ).

For example, if the **sets** are X = {1,2,4}, Y = {2,3,4}, then X union Y = {1,2,3,4} and the median is (2+3)/2=2.5.

This problem is different from computing the median of two **lists**.

For example, if X = {1,2,4}, Y = {2,3,4} are viewed as **lists**, the X union Y = {1,2,3,3,4,4} and the median is (3+3)/2 = 3.

The median of union of **lists** has communication complexity O(log n)  (See [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/45937/communication-complexity-lower-bound-for-computing-median)).

There is a hint in the textbook:

> compute the median of union of sets, as well as the median of the
> union of the lists.

All my methods failed, such as Krapchenko's method or finding a bad sets of inputs. Maybe I didn't use these methods correctly. Could someone help?

Comment: This may be considered to be an exercise, not a research-level question, and so not appropriate for cstheory.se.  If so, maybe try cs.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Can you reduce set disjointness to it?   See e.g. http://dx.doi.org/10.4086/toc.2007.v003a011 .  Or use similar techniques to directly show a lower bound?